# Where do you find your Google Cloud Storage "accessToken"

Tags: android

I'm using Google Cloud Storage from my Android app as follows:

```
private static Storage buildService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport transport =  new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken("***");


    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
        Collection<String> scopes = StorageScopes.all();
        credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
    }

    return new Storage.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Sup GCS")
            .build();
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err: {
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:   "code" : 401,
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:     "domain" : "global",
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:     "location" : "Authorization",
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:     "locationType" : "header",
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:     "reason" : "authError"
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:   } ],
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err:   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
06-02 18:17:51.891 26468-26570/com.sup.sup W/System.err: }
```

I have no clue where to find that accessToken and the docs for Google Cloud Storage Client APIs are hardly of any help. Currently what I pass into the `setAccessToken` method is the *Android Key (auto created by a Google Service* API Key I found on my Developer Console.

I've always known that this isn't the right one, but this was the only kind of credential I have.

What do I send in as my `accessToken`?

**Edit:**
Just for the record, I followed the steps to create a *Service Account Key* because the website said that's what I needed for GCS. I then downloaded a JSON file that got generated. But I have no clue how to authenticate my Android app with that. I don't use any *user data,* but need to use GCS for my app's own data, which means I'll need a **service** account.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I couldn't find my `accessToken` but I found a workaround without having to use an `accessToken` to authenticate. I created a *Service Account Key* (as mentioned in the question's first edit) and a JSON file was downloaded onto my computer. I couldn't, of course, use this file directly, because it'd have to be on my Android phone's filesystem as well.. So here's how I authenticated with that file:

First I took that JSON file and copied the contents into a `String`: (I've censored info, as I felt necessary)

```
private static String credential_json = "{\n" +
            "  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n" +
            "  \"project_id\": \"***\",\n" +
            "  \"private_key_id\": \"***\",\n" +
            "  \"private_key\": \"***\",\n" +
            "  \"client_email\": \"***@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\n" +
            "  \"client_id\": \"***\",\n" +
            "  \"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\n" +
            "  \"token_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token\",\n" +
            "  \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",\n" +
            "  \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/***%40***.iam.gserviceaccount.com\"\n" +
            "}";
```

Next I converted this `credential_json` string into a stream, and created a `GoogleCredential` from this stream. To Google, this was as good as reading from a file:

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(credential_json.getBytes("UTF_8")));
```